# Преобразование массива в int

Tags: java, массивы

Как можно преобразовать весь массив `amatr` , а не только ячейку `amatr[i]`?

```
 char amatr[]=textField3.getText().toCharArray();
 int k1=Integer.valueOf(new String(new char[]{amatr[i]}));
```

Если просто написать

```
int k1=Integer.valueOf(new String(new char[]{amatr}));//error
```

Comment: int k1=Integer.valueOf(textField3.getText());

Зачем вообще Вам нужен массив amatr ?

Comment: Создать видимость работы :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k1=Integer.valueOf(new String(amatr));
```